Jetbrains Plugin Development for multiple IDEs
I created a plugin but it works just for IntelliJ, it does not run on PyCharm even if I could install it.
This is the section I wanted to add PyCharm support:
runPluginVerifier {
    ideVersions.set(listOf(
        "IU-2023.3",   // IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate
        "IC-2023.3",   // IntelliJ IDEA Community
        "PY-2023.3",   // PyCharm Professional
        "PC-2023.3"    // PyCharm Community
    ))
}

But it does not run on PyCharm, how can I solve this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
